# Getting an error when typing in the search box

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json, search

I can't filter out a specific word in the search box when typing in words. I keep getting an error that says

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined'
```

in the console. When I type in the search box I want to return the result of my search. I am using `HTML`, `JSON`, and `Jquery`. Here is my code:

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i"); 
            $.getJSON('bulls.json', function(data) {
                var output = "<ul id='result'>";
                $.each(data, function(key, val){
                if (val.codename.search(regex) != -1) {
                    output += '<div class="col-md-6 well">';
                    output += '<div class="col-md-7">';
                    output += '<h5>' + val.codename + '</h5>';
                    output += '</div>';
                    output += '</div>';
                }
            });
                output += '</ul>';
                $('#bulls-info').html(output);
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: `val.codename` seems to be undefined. Please post your JSON response too.

Comment: I just figure it out, I was missing 'results'. Instead of "$.each(data, function(key, val)" it should be $.each(data.results, function(key, val). Thank you for responding!